# Bash typeset (declare) as integer without variable

Tags: bash, variables

Is it possible to `typeset -i` (synonymous with `declare -i`, [see a manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/declare.html) or [a reference](http://www.museum.state.il.us/ismdepts/library/linuxguides/abs-guide/declareref.html)) in bash without assigning to a variable?

Consider the following example:

```
typeset -i a=42;
foo $a;
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality without using a helper variable?
Assume `foo` is not editable (for example, a binary) with reasonable ease.

Comment: It seems you just want `foo 42`.

Comment: @kojiro In that case the argument is not strictly typed.

Comment: @Nit bash functions don't pass by reference in this way – the *name* carries the integer attribute, not the value. `foo 42` is *identical* to `declare -i a; a=42; foo "$a"`

Comment: @Nit, if `foo` were a binary, passing arguments to it would happen at the OS level by way of a `char** argv` array. This is, by its nature, an array of strings. That's an immutable aspect of any POSIX-compliant operating system; there is no way of passing raw integers to a command.

Comment: No. There is no way to create a name with an attribute, such as the integer attribute or the trace attribute, and have that attribute be passed along with the name to a function as a parameter to that function. If you could modify the function you could use a global name instead of a parameter or, as Charles Duffy already said, `local -i` the name inside the function. Since you cannot modify the function, you really don't have any options. You will have to guarantee the value is an integer before invoking the function.

Comment: ...now, if you want to wrap a binary with a function (or wrapper script) that provides typechecking for its arguments, **that** is a thing we could help you with, but it also would be a different question.

Comment: @kojiro That can be a valid answer, thank you for your input.

Comment: I would, but I don't really feel like trying to hunt for references on why you *can't* do something (that's hard) and I hate giving answers without references.

Comment: You need to read those references you cited, especially the parts on variable substitution. What your example does is create a named variable with the integer attribute and assigns a value to it. That's fine. However, what `foo $a` does is expand the value of the variable into a string, then does word splitting etc. on the line `foo 42` to determine the function/program name and arguments, and then passes the *string* `"42"` to the function/program `foo`. There is no notion of 42 being an integer in the context of `foo` or the site where it is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Put the declaration of type **inside** the function's body. You can use either `declare` or (to be more explicit) `local` for this:

```
foo() {
  local -i arg=$1
  ....
}
```

No other solution is possible without modifying the function's body (or adding a wrapper which performs typechecking before passing the arguments as untyped strings), as **arguments to functions** (and to external commands) **are passed as strings, regardless of any type declarations which may have been made beforehand**.

Comment: +1 This is the _only_ way to ensure the parameter within the function has the integer attribute. There is no way to do it from without.

Comment: Updated question with details why this isn't a sufficient answer.

Comment: @Nit, it's the only answer the language provides.